# angular 2 rc3 router default routes

Tags: angular

We are moving out project from router deprecated to the new angular 2 route.I can't find something Similar to usedefault in the router deprecated.Basically when I load the page we want the url to change to http://website_name/index instead of http://website_name/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RC3**

You can use **redirectTo**, something like :

```
export const YourAppRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/index',
    terminal: true
  },
  {
    path: 'index',
    component: YouMainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '',     component: YouMainComponentList },
      { path: ':id',  component: YouMainComponentDetail }
    ]
  }
];
```

**RC4**

```
export const YourAppRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'index',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'index',
    component: YouMainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '',     component: YouMainComponentList },
      { path: ':id',  component: YouMainComponentDetail }
    ]
  }
];
```

for reference : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect

Comment: They change it a little bit now with the beta, use pathMatch: true instead of terminal. And also their is not need in / in redirectTo

Comment: Thank you Doron..they are changing so fast

Comment: I've included also the code for  RC4 (with @angular/router: 3.0.0-beta.1)

Comment: I think you also need `pathMatch: full` for `path: ''` or `terminal:true` in `RC3`